# Office.Interop.Excel How to get axis from series

Tags: vsto

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to create a chart. Some of my series in chart series collection are logarithmic, so I want to get hold of axis related a particular series, to set scale type to logarithmic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you could do it:

```
xlAxisValue = CType(xlChart.Axes(, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary), Excel.Axes)
xlAxisValue.Item(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).ScaleType = Excel.XlScaleType.xlScaleLogarithmic
```

It is a generic example, if it is not working plese post your code.

Comment: I want to get Axis from series.